# How to install dotnet core 6 webapp on IIS server window 11

Tags: .net-core, iis, publish

According to the web, I should be able to install on Windows 11 (as well as server, et al).
I have an application (Hunter.API), that I can run in debug perfectly - both with Swagger as well as simply entering a Url in the browser (does an http get to a controller that returns some data from SQL Server).

Next: I published using:  dotnet publish -r win-x64   - -self-contained (that's a double dash without the space between).
I created a site on IIS:
[IIS Mgr][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47fK.png

Bindings:  http  localhost  80  *  (wasn't sure what to put for host name; btw, I stopped the default web site that was using port 80.

Basic Settings:  Sitename: HunterAPI  App Pool: HunterAPI
Path:  down to \Hunter\Hunter.API\Bin\Release\net6.0  ??

Then I select from the right panel: Browse localhost on *.80 http  and get the same that the Default Site would have produced.

Tried going to c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ and opened the hosts file.
Added a line  127.0.0.1 HunterAPI.com  (I have no clue; some site said something like that)
Restarted and no change.

Then I changed the binding port number to 8081, restarted.
got 403.14 error which suggested: A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

I'm lost and out of options.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could see that you are using the .Net 6.0. You need to install the [.Net core hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). It will install the .Net Core runtime and IIS support. This is necessary when you host your .Net Core site on the IIS.  Then you could restart the site that you hosted on port 8081 and try to visit it in the browser.

Comment: You will have to know what are IIS site bindings before moving on, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Otherwise, you don't even understand what kind of a site you create and what are the proper URLs to access it. Then for ASP.NET Core web apps, quite a few mistakes can be made when hosting on IIS so running a report can reveal more to you, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html